# matlab: Error/precision when evaluating vector

Tags: matlab

I noticed what was for me an unpredicted behavior when evaluating vectors. It seems is really different doing it directly than indexing within a loop. Can anyone give me some help with this?
i know is probably explained in how it makes each operation, so i need some keys about how to look for it

thanks for advise
thanks in advance

example:

```
x=[0.05:.01:3];
n=size(x,2);
y1 = (8*x-1)/(x)-(exp(x));

for i=1:n
    y2(i)=(8*x(i)-1)/(x(i))-(exp(x(i)));
end

a1=[x;y1];
a2=[x;y2];

plot(x,y1, 'red')
hold on
plot(x,y2, 'blue')
```

here the plot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAHD6.jpg

results:

```
a2:
0.05   -13.0513
0.06   -9.7285
0.07   -7.3582
0.08   -5.5833
0.09   -4.2053
0.10   -3.1052
0.11   -2.2072
0.12   -1.4608
0.13   -0.8311
0.14   -0.2931
0.15   0.1715
0.16   0.5765




a1:
0.05   6.4497
0.06   6.4391
0.07   6.4284
0.08   6.4177
0.09   6.4068
0.10   6.3958
0.11   6.3847
0.12   6.3734
0.13   6.3621
0.14   6.3507
0.15   6.3391
0.16   6.3274
```

Comment: +1 Very well-asked first question.  You gave a small repeatable code snippet and showed your results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is:

```
 y1 = (8*x-1)./(x)-(exp(x));   % note the ./
```

instead of:

```
 y1 = (8*x-1)/(x)-(exp(x));
```

As a side note, you can type `help /` to see what your original first statement was really doing.  It was effectively doing `(x'\(8*x-1)')'` (note the backslash).

Comment: Thanks, very much chris.
I was really stuck with that simple thing.
I didn't realize that trying to divide matrices matlab just do A*B^-1, thats actually very usefull :)
anyway im surprised,  for higher values the results were so similar

thanks again
bye

Comment: For higher values the `exp()` term dominated your result so the first term mattered less.  Keep in mind that `B \ A` is slightly more general than `A*inv(B)` and the former gives something meaningful in some cases where `B` cannot be inverted.

Answer (score 3):

The error is in your first vector calculation of y1. The problem is in the part where you divide by x.  Vector/Matrix division is different from single element division and will return a vector/matrix result.

The solution is to do element-by-element division of these vectors.  The vector notation shortcut for this is to use ./ (dot-divide):

```
y3 = (8*x-1)./(x)-(exp(x));
```

Now you should find that y2 and y3 are identical.